# Quickest/Best way to Format a string

Tags: c#, format

I know this may seem a junior question and it should have been easy to find the solution by Googling it but I am stuck.

I am using C#.

I have this string:

**20150824100112345 (for instance)**

I wish to transform it to a new string like so:

**2015\08\24\10\00\01\12\345**

Is there a '1-liner' of code I can use to accomplish this please?

NB
Without 1st converting it to a datetime format

Comment: You have two problems. One is _"Parse a DateTime string"_, the other is _"Format-print a DateTime"_. Both are thoroughly documented.

Comment: I don't see how a complex one-liner would make your life better than writing 5 simple lines of code and putting them in a method.

Comment: @xanatos I just undeleted this question so I can reply. My thinking is that it would be quicker?  Probably wrong though lol

Comment: @CodeCaster I must be so thick. I still cannot see how I can format it to how I want?

Comment: Show your code. :) `DateTime.ParseExact()` and `parsedDateTime.ToString("formatstring")` are what you're looking for. If you don't care about date validation and your input is always formatted, you can also simply use `string.Substring()`.

Comment: @CodeCaster only reason I had not posted my code was because it was embarrassing to do so. I was trying to covert my input to a datetime first and then format that but the code was very ugly and embarrassing. I will quickly look at what you suggested. thanks

Comment: my question was not well put. I shall amend it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the comments, you should really parse it to a DateTime and then turn that into a string.

But to parse a string as you asked you should use a Regex which can split it into groups.

Comment: but that was the point of my question. I wanted to achieve what I want without converting to a datetime format

Comment: Well done,  I never really bothered with regex but that was the ideal solution. thanks :)

Comment: my soiution in case anyone was following: var f = Regex.Replace(ts, @"(\w{4})(\w{2})(\w{2})(\w{2})(\w{2})(\w{2})(\w{3})", @"$1\$2\$3\$4\$5\$6\$7");

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to parse to DateTime first (i.e. if you don't care about validity) and if the input is always formatted as your example (zero-padded, so `08` instead of `8`), you can do with a few simple `Substring()` calls:

```
string input = "20150824100112345";
string output = input.Substring(0, 4) + @"\" // 2015
              + input.Substring(4, 2) + @"\" // 08
              + input.Substring(6, 2) + @"\" // 24
              + input.Substring(8, 2) + @"\" // 10
              + input.Substring(10, 2) + @"\" // 01
              + input.Substring(12, 2) + @"\" // 12
              + input.Substring(14, 3); // 345
```

Or in Regex:

```
string input = "20150824100112345";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, 
                  "([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{3})", 
                 @"$1\$2\$3\$4\$5\$6\$7");
```

Comment: Thanks for all you help and suggestions. What you had here was what I used before.  I had read somewhere that SubString being repeatedly called (As in my solution) can be a performance hit.  As my app needs to be on 24/7 and as I will be calling this function 30 times at least a second I was just going through my code to optimise as much as I can

Comment: Substring is really fast, and you shouldn't prematurely optimize. If the string concatenation is slowing your process down, consider a StringBuilder.

Comment: Yes, I do use StringBuilder where ever I can,  thanks :)

Comment: @AndrewSimpson It is important to note that you should use `StringBuilder` if you are building your string in a loop (`for`/`foreach`/...)... simple string concatenations are often faster if done directly with the `+` operator. For example, the code of CodeCaster is converted to a `string.Concat(...)` of the various substrings (see http://goo.gl/b7fFre). The only way to do it faster would be **perhaps** to do something like https://ideone.com/01aw02, that is using a special overload of `StringBuilder` that doesn't require creating useless temporary substrings...

Comment: @xanatos thanks for all that.  very useful that overloading of the stringbuilder. I never knew that. Great stuff!